# How to open hyperlinks based on selection with chrome in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, google-chrome, hyperlink

I know you can do

```
Sub Chrome()

Dim chromePath As String
chromePath = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
Shell (chromePath & " -url https://www.google.com")
Shell (chromePath & " -url path")
Shell (chromePath & " -url path")
Shell (chromePath & " -url path")
Shell (chromePath & " -url path")

End Sub
```

But if I do not know the hyperlinks or URL'¿s beforehand I can't really writhe them in the code, I do have cells with hyperlinks, I'm trying to accomplish to be able to select an X amount of cells and open the hyperlinks in different tabs in Chrome.

I tried something stupid along the lines of

```
Sub Open_HyperLinks()

Dim chromePath As String
chromePath = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
    Dim hl As Hyperlink
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each hl In Selection.Hyperlinks
        Shell (chromePath & " -url hl")
    Next hl
End Sub
```

of course that did not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the *.Address* property of each *Hyperlink* in the [Hyperlinks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839966.aspx) collection.

```
Sub Open_HyperLinks()
    Dim chromePath As String, hl As Hyperlink

    chromePath = Environ("PROGRAMFILES(X86)") & "\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    'On Error Resume Next
    For Each hl In Selection.Hyperlinks
        Shell chromePath & " -url " & hl.Address
    Next hl
End Sub
```

I resolved your %PROGRAMFILES(X86)% environment variable out from scratch but a hardcoded drive and path should work just as well.

Comment: ... Is there a way to force a time between opening the tabs for some reason when opening the tabs they open in a random order... I need them to open from top to bottom...

Comment: You might try adding the `-newtab` parameter to the command line (as proposed in another answer) but I do not have much experience in operating Chrome from VBA, only in launching applications from a shell. There are several ways you can wait a predetermined number of seconds but unless it is IE, I do not believe you can wait until Chrome has finished loading the URL without determining processor or network activity from the O/S's vantage point.

Comment: So lets wait we want to wait 5 seconds should I use `wait` `timeout` or both?

Comment: `dim then as double: then =now+timerserial(0, 0, 5): do while now<then: doevents: loop`

Answer (score 0):

The Shell() method passes all arguments as a string to the command line. Make sure your hl object in " -url hl" is outside of the quotations. Otherwise Shell() passes "hl" as the hyperlink instead of "https://www.google.com".

For the same reason, get rid of the extra quotations around chromePath.

Try this:

```
Sub Open_HyperLinks()

    Dim chromePath As String
    chromePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
        Dim hl As Hyperlink
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each hl In Selection.Hyperlinks
            Shell (chromePath & " -url -newtab " & hl)
        Next hl
End Sub
```

Note: I have not tested these flags for the chrome executable.

Comment: Try replacing "hl" with "hl.Address" in the Shell() call